# bash script get substring from string

Tags: shell, scripting

I need get a part of string depending on some value from a long string (for example some output from ps -ef).

for example source string:

```
long_string1="cmd ... -aaaa=A -bbbb=B -zzzz=Z -DHOME=/home/user/xxx -cccc=C ... etc."
```

or

```
long_string2="cmd ... -aaaa=A -DHOME=/home/user/xxx -bbbb=B -zzzz=Z -cccc=C ... etc."
```

I want extract or get following subtring only after **-DHOME=** :

```
/home/user/xxx
```

Position of "**-DHOME=**" is not fixed, it could be anywhere in long_string.

I am using following command:

```
echo $long_string1|sed -e 's/.*-DHOME=//g;s/ -cccc=C.*//g'
```

it works fine for $long_string1 but it doesn't work for $long_string2.

It will work only when "**-cccc=C**" will be netx to "**-DHOME=**" :-(

How can I get path after "**-DHOME=**" but not depend on next values e.g. "**-cccc=C**" ???

Is there any more effective way or regexp to get same output ?

Thanks
M.Gi

Comment: OR, once you have removed stuff before `-DHOME=`, search for the first space and delete everything after that? i.e. `s/ .*$//'`? Good luck.

Comment: does your shell support `var="abc def" ; echo ${var/ *}` ?

Comment: Also, in the future, **this** is why you see constant streams of comments **show us your code** . Don't make people guess what you are doing  ;-)

Comment: thank you @shellter

both s/ .*$//' and var="abc def" ; echo ${var/ *} working fine, but I will run it on Linux,HPUX,AIX,Sun ...

Comment: `bash` is bash on all OS's (excepting those old-line unixen probably have ver 2 installed by default ;-( ) . Again, these are more "requirements" that should have been in your main Q. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` and `cut` can help you.

```
#!/bin/bash
get_home() { awk -F "DHOME=" '{print $2}' <<< "${long_string}" | cut -d ' ' -f1; }

long_string="cmd ... -aaaa=A -bbbb=B -zzzz=Z -DHOME=/home/user/xxx -cccc=C ... etc."
get_home
long_string="cmd ... -aaaa=A -DHOME=/home/user/xxx -bbbb=B -zzzz=Z -cccc=C ... etc."
get_home
long_string="cmd ... -aaaa=A -DHOME=/home/user/xxx"
get_home
```

Output

```
/home/user/xxx
/home/user/xxx
/home/user/xxx
```

`awk` splits the input on "DHOME=" and prints the second part.
`cut` then splits on spaces and gets the first part.  Obviously, this will not work correctly if the name of the folder contains spaces.  Usually, home directories don't have spaces in their names.

Comment: Good idea about using DHOME= as the `FS`, but you don't need to pipe to cut, i.e. `awk -F 'DHOME=' '{line=$2 ; split(line, arr, " "); print arr[1]} <<< "$long_string"` will work too. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in pure-bash style, credits to [`shelter`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) for suggestions.

```
#!/bin/bash

long_string="cmd ... -aaaa=A -bbbb=B -zzzz=Z -DHOME=/home/user/xxx -cccc=C ... etc."

tempString1="${long_string##*-DHOME=}"  # Strips off everything upto '-DHOME='
tempString2="${tempString1/ *}"  # Strips off everything until first whitespace

echo "$tempString2"
```

Running it in console:-

```
$ ./myScript.sh
/home/user/xxx
```